# epiphany plugin for password storage

Tags: password, plugin

I am looking for a [keepass](http://keepass.info/) plugin for epiphany. Something like [PassIFox](https://github.com/pfn/passifox/) for Firefox: PassIFox "behaves" like a new password storage for firefox - and redirects all queries (fetch/store etc..) to keepass.

Since I am not sure whether such a plugin exists for epiphany I'd also take every hint on how to create a similar plugin for epiphany...

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that epiphany uses seahorse for password storage and its integrated already.

Comment: Matthew: that means I can forget about combining epiphany and keepass or should I look for a solution to combine seahorse and keepass ?

Comment: Seahorse looks to do the same (and perhaps more) of what keeppass is doing.

Comment: maybe it does the same, but it's not available in Windows and Android ;-)